# Angular js 2 Tutorials for Beginners

Tags: angular

For past two days i'm learning Angular 2 and i didn't learnt angular 1 , but still i cant able to get how to use and how to code in angular 2 , can anyone please suggest some tutorials and video materials for beginners in angular 2.  I created one component but that is not running properly , this is my app.components how can i include new component in this app.component.ts , if my component is TutorialComponent

```
     @Component({
       selector: 'my-app',
       template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`,
        })
     export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular'; }
```

Comment: Recommendations on finding a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are considered [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on [so].

Comment: Angularjs is a javascript framework, if you know the javascript programming concept, you wouldn't have any problem programming nj app

Comment: There are litteraly loads of tutorials for beginners you can access from searching Google to searching YouTube, just typing 'angular 2 begginers tutorial' in any search and checking first few ones will do it.

Comment: Two days and you're still not an expert? Oh man I'm sorry to hear that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience it is best to learn by doing. The first thing that I would do is watch this video.

[Angular 4 in 60 Minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhzGSHNhnbI&t=1183s)

The teacher gives a rundown of all the capabilities of the latest version of Angular. As he goes through the tutorial it is important to be following along in your favorite editor.

After doing this you should starting looking for more tutorials on Udemy, Pluralsight, etc. I found this particual tutorial on pluralsight to be very
good.

[Angular: Getting Started](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/angular-2-getting-started-update)

The instructor, Deborah, does a really good job of helping the student to visualize what the structure of an Angular application is like.

When you are done with the things above you should be able to tackle your own projects. Start with a simple sketch and idea, keep things simple. When you are satisfied with a direction start coding. Make sure you keep making strives to gain a solid foundation in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.